# Only allow remote command with credentials

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I have `server A` and a `server B` in the same domain (Windows Server 2012 R2):

```
PS C:\Deployment> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

I have an admin user on server B which is called `WORKGROUP\test`.

On both servers I performed:

```
enable-psremoting -force
```

On `server A` I performed:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServerName -ScriptBlock {
   get-childitem
   get-service
}
```

This works. Now I'm using credentials:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER3 -Credential you-user -ScriptBlock { get-service }
```

When I run it I got this view (picture from internet):

[image: https://i-technet.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC702024.png]

When I give the right credentials it works, when I provide the wrong credentials it doesn't work. So that's fine.
But when I just click "Cancel" it also works. It seems like the remote server (`server B`) does not require credentials. What do I have to change to make it also fail when you provide no credentials?

Comment: `Users need to use the credential request` - Why?  What are  you hoping this would accomplish?  By default psremoting will use kerberos authentication.  The users will have provided proper credentials when authenticating on the source system.

Comment: Users can start the powershellscript from one server which contains all the users (AD, all the users are on all the servers but not everyone has the same permissons). So some users can authentice and run the command. Others can't.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Invoke-Command` command, you could use the option `-credential`

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command):

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01 -Credential domain01\user01 -ScriptBlock {Get-Culture}
```

Comment: Users need to use the credential request. So I just need to find a way how I obligate to give right credentials and not allow no credentials (clicking cancel). So some way I say on server B: only right credentials can access (now it's: only right OR NO credentials can access)

Comment: Have you tried with `-Authentication` option ? By default, `Invoke-Command` doesn't need credentials, so if you do cancel it will take the crrent user.

Answer (score 0):

If the current user is allowed access to the PowerShell endpoint on the remote machine, they'll always be able to remote in without providing explicit credentials.

The only way to require providing explicit credentials is to break that chain.
Some options:

- Create a new user on the remote host that is an administrator, and remove the remote users from membership in groups allowed to connect.  This is somewhat equivalent to the `sudo` approach.
- Reconfigure the default PowerShell endpoint (or remove and create a new one) to change the permissions of who is allowed to connect.  By default, Microsoft.PowerShell endpoint looks like this:

> `Get-PSSessionConfiguration`
>
> Name          : microsoft.powershell
>   PSVersion     : 5.1
>   StartupScript :
>   RunAsUser     :
>   Permission    : NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE AccessAllowed, BUILTIN\Administrators AccessAllowed, BUILTIN\Remote Management Users AccessAllowed

As long as the remote user isn't in one of those groups - or you remove those groups and use new ones - they'll have to provide an explicit credential to connect.  That might be using a `-Credential` directly on an `Invoke-Command`, or when creating a Session.

If you consider that option, consider going all the way in and looking at [Just Enough Administration (`JEA`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn896648.aspx) where you can specify three main options:

1. Who can connect
2. What can they do
3. Who will their command run as.

JEA can be the start of a strong foundation of limiting what administrators can do for particular circumstances. This can be part of [Role Based Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) (`RBAC`).